# Visual Studio 2015 - Code style settings

Tags: visual-studio, coding-style, visual-studio-2015

In the new Visual Studio 2015 I get the following "Name can be simplified" quick action. I prefer using `String` over `string` when using the static methods of the String class because gives a better overview.

[image]

I have looked for an option to customize this under: `TOOLS -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Code Style`, but there was not much there.

Is there anyway I can customize this settings? Or even better if I can customize these settings for everyone working on the solution/project? So everyone uses the same coding style.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I just came across this myself and agree on `String` vs `string` for static methods. I think you were correct in looking in `TOOLS -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Code Style`, because I unticked "Prefer intrinsic predefined type keyword in member access expressions" and this got rid of the "Name can be simplified" message that I was experiencing.

Did you try this or are you looking to have more control over the customisations?

Comment: No. I didn't try that one. But I seems to have been what I was looking for. It would be awesome if could have even more control over the customization though.

Comment: @Nexith StyleCop will give you the customization you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can now add .editorconfig file and opt-out intrinsic predefined type keyword for expressions:

```
dotnet_style_predefined_type_for_member_access = false:warning
```

Here is a [reference file](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/.editorconfig) from Roslyn repo.